# Prevent updating "modified time" when copying files to a mounted Samba folder

Tags: mount, samba, date, copy

I don’t want the “last modified” attribute to be updated with the current date when I am copying files to a mounted Samba folder. How can I avoid this behaviour ?

> This behaviour occurs with (K)Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 15.10.
>
> This behaviour can be reproduced using

- GUI tools: file browsers (tested with *nautilus 3.4.2* and *dolphin 2.0*), sync-tools and
- CLI commands: `cp -p` in the terminal.

The Samba folder was mounted to the local file system either with:

- `sudo mount -t smbfs //mynas/folder /mnt/nas/ -o user=username` or
- `sudo mount -t cifs //mynas/folder /home/mnt/nas/ -o user=username`.

**Notes:**

- When connecting to the same Samba folder (either with *nautilus* or *dolphin*) using a URL like `smb://username@mynas/folder/` then I can copy files to it without having the “modified time” attribute replaced with the current time!
- But mounting a Samba folder is more convenient and also, not all tools support the smb protocol. This is, why using the URI `smb://` is not a workaround for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp "last modified" remains (and will not be replaced by the current time) when adding proper group and user IDs to the mount command, e.g.:

`sudo mount -t cifs //mynas/folder mnt/mynas/folder -o user=username,gid=1000,uid=1000`